# Consumer, producer- mutex, sync- critical section

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex, thread-synchronization

I've tried typical some example of multithreading, after that I would like to try typical producer-consumer problem.

(Producer can produce if there's space and also if consumer is not consuming and vice versa)

But I have problem with shared-resources, is in java something like semaphores in C ? (usage with wait and post functions)

- I have found synchronized example
- but I would like to try something which can I control manually (like semaphores in C)

I have:

- `class MyThread implements Runnable`-  basic class for my Threads
- `class Producer extends MyThread`- producer thread
- `class Consumer extends MyThread`- consumer class
- `class ThreadContainer`- shared resources (stock)

In `ThreadContainer` I have prepared some lock, which I found and tried, but that doesnt works as should:

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)Running Consumer 0 [1]
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
(etc.)
```

I will be grateful if somebody explain me "how to".

Classes below

MyThread:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;

    private ThreadContainer container;

    MyThread(String name, ThreadContainer cont) {
        threadName = name;
        this.container = cont;
        System.out.println("Creating " + threadName);
    }

    public void run() {

    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    public ThreadContainer getContainer() {
        return container;
    }

    public String getThreadName() {
        return threadName;
    }
}
```

Producer:

```
 public class Producer extends MyThread {

    Producer(String name, ThreadContainer cont) {
        super(name, cont);
    }

    public void produce(int amount) {
        super.getContainer().produce(amount);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running " + super.getThreadName());
        try {
            for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {

                synchronized (super.getContainer().lock) {
                    System.out.println(super.getThreadName()
                            + " want to produce: " + i);
                    while (!super.getContainer().canProduce(i)) {
                        super.getContainer().lock.wait();
                    }
                    System.out.println(super.getThreadName() + " producing: "
                            + i);
                    super.getContainer().produce(i);
                    System.out.println("Container state: "
                            + super.getContainer());
                }

            }

            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread " + super.getThreadName()
                    + " interrupted.");
        }

        System.out.println("Thread " + super.getThreadName() + " exiting.");
    }

}
```

Consumer:

```
 public class Consumer extends MyThread {

    Consumer(String name, ThreadContainer cont) {
        super(name, cont);
    }

    public void consume(int am) {
        super.getContainer().consume(am);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running " + super.getThreadName());
        try {
            for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
                synchronized (super.getContainer().lock) {
                    System.out.println(super.getThreadName()
                            + " want to consume: " + i);
                    while (!super.getContainer().canConsume(i)) {
                        super.getContainer().lock.wait();
                    }
                    System.out.println(super.getThreadName() + " consuming: "
                            + i);
                    super.getContainer().consume(i);
                    System.out.println("Container state: "
                            + super.getContainer());
                }
            }

            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread " + super.getThreadName()
                    + " interrupted.");
        }

        System.out.println("Thread " + super.getThreadName() + " exiting.");
    }

}
```

Container:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ThreadContainer {
    private int capacity;
    private int value;

    private Lock locky = new ReentrantLock(true);

    public ThreadContainer(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.value = 0; 
    }

    public void produce(int amount){
        if(this.value + amount <= this.capacity){
            this.value += amount;
        }else{
            this.value = capacity;
        }
    }

    public void consume(int amount){
        if(this.value - amount >= 0 ){
            this.value -= amount;
        }else{
            this.value =0;
        } 
    }

    public boolean canProduce(int am){
        return (this.value + am) <= this.capacity;
    }

    public boolean canConsume(int am){
        return (this.value - am) >= 0;
    }

    public boolean tryLock(){
        if(this.locky.tryLock()){
            this.locky.lock();
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void unlock(){
        this.locky.unlock();
        this.locky.notify();
    }

    public void waitLock() throws InterruptedException{
        this.locky.wait();
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "capacity: " + this.capacity + ", value: " + this.value;
    }

}
```

MainClass:

```
public class RunFrom {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ThreadContainer container = new ThreadContainer(25);

        /*
        Producer prod = new Producer("Producer", container);
        prod.start();

        Consumer cons = new Consumer("Consumer", container);
        cons.start();
        */

        int prodCount =0;
        int conCount =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if(i%2 == 0){
                Producer prod = new Producer("Producer " + prodCount + " [" + i + "]", container);
                prodCount++;
                prod.start();
            }else{
                Consumer cons = new Consumer("Consumer " + conCount + " [" + i + "]", container);
                conCount++;
                cons.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

So, I made modification as follows @fildor [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) in post 
It looks like if it works for 2 threads ok (1 consumer and 1 producer), but still there is a problem while I creates more threads..

- MyThread same as original
- consumer just consume
- producer just produce
- locking is solved in stock container

Consumer

```
//...
    try {
                for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
                    System.out.println(super.getThreadName() + " want to consume: "
                            + i);
                    System.out.println(super.getThreadName() + " consuming: " + i);
                    super.getContainer().consume(i);
                    System.out.println("Container state: " + super.getContainer());
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Thread " + super.getThreadName()
                        + " interrupted.");
            }
//...
```

Producer

```
//...
try {
            for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println(super.getThreadName() + " want to produce: "
                        + i);
                System.out.println(super.getThreadName() + " producing: " + i);
                super.getContainer().produce(i);
                System.out.println("Container state: " + super.getContainer());
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread " + super.getThreadName()
                    + " interrupted.");
        }
//...
```

Stock container

```
//...
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    final Condition notFull = lock.newCondition();
    final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
//...

public void produce(int amount) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (!canProduce(amount)) {
                notFull.wait();
            }

            if (this.value + amount <= this.capacity) {
                this.value += amount;
            } else {
                this.value = capacity;
            }
            notEmpty.signal();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException" + e);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void consume(int amount) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (!canConsume(amount)) {
                notEmpty.wait();
            }

            if (this.value - amount >= 0) {
                this.value -= amount;
            } else {
                this.value = 0;
            }
            notFull.signal();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException" + e);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

for 4 threads (2 producers and 2 consumers) output looks like:

```
Creating Producer 0 [0]
Starting Producer 0 [0]
Running Producer 0 [0]
Producer 0 [0] want to produce: 10
Producer 0 [0] producing: 10
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Creating Consumer 0 [1]
Starting Consumer 0 [1]
Creating Producer 1 [2]
Starting Producer 1 [2]
Creating Consumer 1 [3]
Running Consumer 0 [1]
Starting Consumer 1 [3]
Creating Producer 2 [4]
Starting Producer 2 [4]
Running Producer 1 [2]
Producer 1 [2] want to produce: 10
Producer 1 [2] producing: 10
Consumer 0 [1] want to consume: 10
Consumer 0 [1] consuming: 10
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 20
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Running Consumer 1 [3]
Consumer 1 [3] want to consume: 10
Running Producer 2 [4]
Producer 2 [4] want to produce: 10
Producer 2 [4] producing: 10
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 20
Consumer 1 [3] consuming: 10
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 0 [0] want to produce: 9
Producer 0 [0] producing: 9
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 19
Consumer 0 [1] want to consume: 9
Consumer 0 [1] consuming: 9
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 1 [2] want to produce: 9
Producer 1 [2] producing: 9
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 19
Producer 2 [4] want to produce: 9
Producer 2 [4] producing: 9
Exception in thread "Producer 2 [4]" Consumer 1 [3] want to consume: 9
Consumer 1 [3] consuming: 9
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at test.ThreadContainer.produce(ThreadContainer.java:24)
    at test.Producer.run(Producer.java:21)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Producer 0 [0] want to produce: 8
Producer 0 [0] producing: 8
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 18
Consumer 0 [1] want to consume: 8
Consumer 0 [1] consuming: 8
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 1 [2] want to produce: 8
Producer 1 [2] producing: 8
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 18
Consumer 1 [3] want to consume: 8
Consumer 1 [3] consuming: 8
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 0 [0] want to produce: 7
Producer 0 [0] producing: 7
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 17
Consumer 0 [1] want to consume: 7
Consumer 0 [1] consuming: 7
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 1 [2] want to produce: 7
Producer 1 [2] producing: 7
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 17
Consumer 1 [3] want to consume: 7
Consumer 1 [3] consuming: 7
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 0 [0] want to produce: 6
Producer 0 [0] producing: 6
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 16
Consumer 0 [1] want to consume: 6
Consumer 0 [1] consuming: 6
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 1 [2] want to produce: 6
Producer 1 [2] producing: 6
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 16
Consumer 1 [3] want to consume: 6
Consumer 1 [3] consuming: 6
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 0 [0] want to produce: 5
Producer 0 [0] producing: 5
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 15
Consumer 0 [1] want to consume: 5
Consumer 0 [1] consuming: 5
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 1 [2] want to produce: 5
Producer 1 [2] producing: 5
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 15
Consumer 1 [3] want to consume: 5
Consumer 1 [3] consuming: 5
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 0 [0] want to produce: 4
Producer 0 [0] producing: 4
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 14
Consumer 0 [1] want to consume: 4
Consumer 0 [1] consuming: 4
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 1 [2] want to produce: 4
Producer 1 [2] producing: 4
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 14
Consumer 1 [3] want to consume: 4
Consumer 1 [3] consuming: 4
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 0 [0] want to produce: 3
Producer 0 [0] producing: 3
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 13
Consumer 0 [1] want to consume: 3
Consumer 0 [1] consuming: 3
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 1 [2] want to produce: 3
Producer 1 [2] producing: 3
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 13
Consumer 1 [3] want to consume: 3
Consumer 1 [3] consuming: 3
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 0 [0] want to produce: 2
Producer 0 [0] producing: 2
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 12
Consumer 0 [1] want to consume: 2
Consumer 0 [1] consuming: 2
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 1 [2] want to produce: 2
Producer 1 [2] producing: 2
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 12
Consumer 1 [3] want to consume: 2
Consumer 1 [3] consuming: 2
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 0 [0] want to produce: 1
Producer 0 [0] producing: 1
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 11
Consumer 0 [1] want to consume: 1
Consumer 0 [1] consuming: 1
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Producer 1 [2] want to produce: 1
Producer 1 [2] producing: 1
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 11
Consumer 1 [3] want to consume: 1
Consumer 1 [3] consuming: 1
Container state: capacity: 25, value: 10
Thread Producer 0 [0] exiting.
Thread Consumer 0 [1] exiting.
Thread Producer 1 [2] exiting.
Thread Consumer 1 [3] exiting.
```

Isn't there problem because more consumers are waiting for same signal as more producers for another one?

Comment: Example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) should help you I guess ...

Comment: There are dozens of different kinds of examples that could be found by Googling a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really read a *Threads in Java 101* tutorial somewhere. The Exception you are getting is because you are waiting on an object without acquiring the intrinsic lock. Given any object identified with `lock`, idiomatic code is:

```
synchronized (lock) {
  while (!condition) {
    lock.wait();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why read tutorials when you can just post every single error message you get on SO.

Comment: So, that solution with synchronized is also bad? :D

Comment: Btw @Kayaman Instead of finding that I'm doing wrong, it would be better to wrote what am I doing wrong ;) just FYI

Comment: I'm writing a stripped down code sample just for fun - but really nobody is willing to debug a hundred line, bad written, multithreaded code without any business context

Comment: Not for fun exactly, but just to try & learn something about that problem :)

Comment: There are too many things you should understand before taking advantage of a code review. If **you** are willing to learn, look at [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/8f2434ac9e3ba130c480) I just wrote

Comment: I have edited original post, now synchronized block should be correct (in param is just lock, not whole object container), inside made wait for that lock

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx It would be a waste of my time. You should be the one Googling, since there are thousands of correct examples even on StackOverflow. Learn to help yourself.

Comment: @Kayaman ofcourse, in this case is also writing "Why read tutorials when you can just post every single error message you get on SO" wasting of your time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated?

What's the benefit of your `MyThread` class?  All I see there is code for starting a thread.  I don't need to define a new class for that.  I can start a new thread with one line of code:

```
new Thread(new Producer(...)).start;
```

---

Then there's your `ThreadContainer` class which has methods that are only meant to be called by the consumer thread, and other methods that are only meant to be called by the producer thread.  That violates a basic design principle:  Each class should only be responsible for *one thing*.

A lot of your code is glue that binds things to other things. (e.g., getter and setter methods are glue, and your `MyThread` class is nothing but glue).  Binding things to other things is called *coupling*, and when you have a lot of it, that's called *tight coupling*.

The more tightly coupled the pieces of your program, the harder the program will be to understand, and change.  Tightly coupled systems are more likely to be broken, and they're harder to diagnose and repair if they are broken.

*Loose coupling* is always better:  Don't make classes and methods *depend* on one another when it isn't absolutely necessary.

---

Finally, If I wanted to demonstrate the producer/consumer concept, I would not clutter the demo with wait()/notify().  The wait() and notify() methods are *low-level primitives* that are meant to be used in the implementation of higher level synchronization objects, and they should be hidden from the code that operates at the higher level.

If you want to demonstrate wait()/notify(), that's one thing.  If you want to demonstrate producer/consumer, that's another.  I would not try to cram both demos into one program.  Each concept only gets in the way of showing off the other.

The Java standard library provides lots of ready-made, higher-level synchronization objects you can use.  Probably the most versatile is a `BlockingQueue`.  My producer/consumer demo would have a producer thread that stuffs "products" into an `ArrayBlockingQueue`, and a consumer thread that pulls them out and operates on them.